# Printing off VBA Scripts. What is the best way to modify formatting of printout?

Tags: vba, excel, printing

This is going to sound absurdly stupid but here we go.

Over the course of my job this summer, I have developed several tools using VBA for the company. I am going back to school and in order to get credit for the job (and waive an internship requirement) I need to show what I've done.

In an appendix, my teacher would like to see the raw coding from my macros.

Now I know that I can print the script out directly from VBA but I am not able to format that the way that I would like before printing.

In addition, I would like to have the printout maintain the formatting from VBA (so tabbed lines and colored text) which I noticed printing it does not do.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could use to print out my scripts?

Thanks,

That guy who is hopelessly lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy and paste the code into Notepad++, and save it as VB code, you can set the print setting (under Settings, Preferences, Print) to WYSIWYG.

Then, when you print it out, it will give you the indentation and colour coding.

Comment: Awesome! Appreciate it!

Comment: Of course, sorry about that the button wasn't appearing on my work computer (neither were the up-vote and down-vote arrows).